# spring integrationflow does not set the message listener on receivercontainer

Tags: spring, integration, amqp, dispatcher, subscriber

We use spring-integration (4.3.12) together with spring-amqp(1.7.4) to send and receive messages between micro services.
To keep out the integration/amqp configuration stuff out of the micro services, we want to use a library containing integration/amqp factories for creation of the objects required.

## What I expect:

I create an IntegrationFlow instance with a messageHandler/messageHandler method (see below for the code) and a SimpleMessageHandlerContainer. When I send a message to the bound exchange then IO expect the messageHandler gets called with the message.

## What do I get:

An exception: "MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers"

If I use the MessageListenerContainer directly (set the messageHandler direct at the container) then I get the message as expected.
I guess, the problem lies within the programmatically initialization of the integrationFlow, but I cant find any information what I´m doing wrong.
Can anybody give me a hint?
Thanx

## Now the code used:

```
public IntegrationFlow createMessageNotifierIntegrationFlow(//
        String brokerNameSpace, String messageHandlerNameSpace, //
        Object messageHandler, String methodName) {
    ConnectionFactory cf = createConnectionFactory(brokerNameSpace);
    AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin = createAmqpAdmin(brokerNameSpace, cf);
    Inbound inbound = createInbound(messageHandlerNameSpace);
    Queue queue = createQueue(messageHandlerNameSpace, amqpAdmin, inbound);

    MessageNotifierIntegrationFlowBuilder builder = MessageNotifierIntegrationFlowBuilder
            .newBuilder(messageHandlerNameSpace, this);
    IntegrationFlow integrationFlow = builder//
            .withConnectionFactory(cf)//
            .withMessageHandler(messageHandler)//
            .withMessageHandlerMethod(methodName)//
            .withFlowExceptionHandler(new FlowExceptionHandler())//
            .withInbound(inbound)//
            .withAmqpAdmin(amqpAdmin)//
            .withInboundQueue(queue)//
            .build();
    String beanName = brokerNameSpace + "-" + messageHandlerNameSpace + "-" + inbound.getQueue();

    return integrationFlow;
}
 
 public IntegrationFlow build() {
        LOGGER.info("creating IntegrationFlow for {}", inbound.getQueue());
        validateBuilder();
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer receiverContainer = amqpObjectFactory.createMessageListenerContainer(//
                inbound, connectionFactory, //
                flowExceptionHandler, inboundQueue, messageHandlerNameSpace);
        final AmqpInboundChannelAdapterSpec adapter = (AmqpInboundChannelAdapterSpec) Amqp.inboundAdapter(receiverContainer);

        StandardIntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows //
                .from(adapter) //
                .log("receiveData")//
                .transform(TO_STRING_TRANSFORMER) //
                .handle(messageHandler, messageHandlerMethod) //
                .log("to message handler").get();
        // flow.start() maybe later?
        flow.start();
        return flow;
    }

       public SimpleMessageListenerContainer createMessageListenerContainer(//
            final Inbound inbound, //
            final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, //
            final FlowExceptionHandler flowExceptionHandler, //
            final Queue inboundQueue, String messageHandlerNameSpace) {
        final String beanName = messageHandlerNameSpace + "-container-" + inbound.getQueue();
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = null;
        container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
        container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(inbound.getMaxconsumers());
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(inbound.getMinconsumers());
        container.setStartConsumerMinInterval(inbound.getMininterval());
        container.addQueues(inboundQueue);
        container.setAcknowledgeMode(inbound.getAckmode());
        container.setDefaultRequeueRejected(inbound.getRequeueRejected());
        container.setErrorHandler(flowExceptionHandler);
        container.setRecoveryInterval(RECOVERY_INTERVAL);
        container.setAutoStartup(false);

        return container;
    }
```